# School project - string grid continuously redrawing

Tags: loops, delphi, tstringgrid

I am doing a project for school. I have written code to populate two string grids in a calendar style. The second string grid (`StringGrid2`) shows the month after the first (`StringGrid1`). This is all done in the following `upDateCalendar()` procedure that receives an integer `iMonthChange` to indicate if the user wants to view one month forward (`iMonthchange := 1`) or one month back (`iMonthChange := -1`).

Here is the populating procedure:

```
procedure TStudentDashboard.upDateCalendar(iMonthChange: integer);
var
  iNumDaysinMonth, iWeekCount: integer;
  tNewMonthStart, tTempMonth: TDateTime;
  tYear, tMonth, tDay: Word;
  I, ARow: integer;
begin
  // date inputs
  tFirstStudyDate := dtpicker.Date;

  updateCheckBoxes;

  iStudySessionDuration :=
    strToInt((cmbStudySessionLength.Items[cmbStudySessionLength.ItemIndex][1] +
    cmbStudySessionLength.Items[cmbStudySessionLength.ItemIndex][2]));

  tLastStudyDate := arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].lastStudyDate
    (tFirstStudyDate, iStudySessionDuration, arrWeekDaysSelected);

  bDrawPastTestDate := false;

  // populate fixed row
  for I := 0 to StringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
    StringGrid1.Rows[I].Clear;

  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0] := 'Mon';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 0] := 'Tue';
  StringGrid1.Cells[2, 0] := 'Wed';
  StringGrid1.Cells[3, 0] := 'Thu';
  StringGrid1.Cells[4, 0] := 'Fri';
  StringGrid1.Cells[5, 0] := 'Sat';
  StringGrid1.Cells[6, 0] := 'Sun';

  // increment month
  tNewMonthStart := IncMonth(tCurrentShowMonthStart, iMonthChange);
  iWeekCount := 1;
  tTempMonth := tNewMonthStart;

  for I := 1 to DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart) do
  begin

    tTempMonth := IncDay(tNewMonthStart, I - 1);

    if (arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate <> 'click here to book') or
      (bBookingTest = true) then
    begin
      if (arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate <> 'click here to book') then
      begin
        tTestDate := strToDate(arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate);
      end
      else
      begin
        tTestDate := dtpckerTestDate.Date;
      end;

      if tTempMonth = tTestDate then
      begin

        StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
          IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));

        iCalendarATestDateXVal := DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1;
        iCalendarATestDateYVal := iWeekCount;
        bDrawPastTestDate := true;
      end
      else
      begin

        StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
          IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      end;

      if (tTempMonth < StrToDate(arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate))
        and (I = DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart)) then
      begin
        bDrawPastTestDate := true;
        iCalendarATestDateXVal := 6;
        iCalendarATestDateYVal := 6;
      end;
      if (tTempMonth > StrToDate(arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate))
        and (I = 1) then
      begin

        bDrawPastTestDate := true;
        iCalendarATestDateXVal := 0;
        iCalendarATestDateYVal := 0;
      end;

    end
    else
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      bDrawPastTestDate := false;
    end;

    if (tTempMonth < tLastStudyDate) and (I = DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart)) then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set at last cell because date to stop colouring is on next stringgrid/month
      iCalendarALastStudyDateXVal := 6;
      iCalendarALastStudyDateYVal := 6;
    end;

    if (tTempMonth > tLastStudyDate) and (I = 1) then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set at last cell because date to stop colouring is on previous month
      iCalendarALastStudyDateXVal := 0;
      iCalendarALastStudyDateYVal := 0;
    end;

    if tTempMonth = tLastStudyDate then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      iCalendarALastStudyDateXVal := DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1;
      iCalendarALastStudyDateYVal := iWeekCount;

    end;

    if (tTempMonth < tFirstStudyDate) and (I = DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart)) then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set at last cell because date to stop colouring is on next stringgrid/month
      iCalendarAFirstStudyDateXVal := 6;
      iCalendarAFirstStudyDateYVal := 6;
    end;

    if (tTempMonth > tFirstStudyDate) and (I = 1) then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set at last cell because date to stop colouring is on previous month
      iCalendarAFirstStudyDateXVal := 0;
      iCalendarAFirstStudyDateYVal := 0;
    end;

    if tTempMonth = tLastStudyDate then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set date x and y values to be highlighted
      iCalendarAFirstStudyDateXVal := DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1;
      iCalendarAFirstStudyDateYVal := iWeekCount;

    end;

    if DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) = 7 then
    begin
      Inc(iWeekCount);
    end;

  end;
  // iMonth1LastXVal := DayOfWeek(IncDay(tNewMonthStart,
  // (DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart) - 1) - 1)) - 1;
  // iMonth1LastYVal := iWeekCount;

  tCurrentShowMonthStart := tNewMonthStart;
  lblMonth1.Caption := LongMonthNames[MonthOf(tCurrentShowMonthStart)];
  lblMonth2.Caption := LongMonthNames
    [MonthOf(IncMonth(tCurrentShowMonthStart))];
  lblYear1.Caption := IntToStr(YearOf(tCurrentShowMonthStart));
  lblYear2.Caption := IntToStr(YearOf(IncMonth(tCurrentShowMonthStart)));

  // populate fixed row
  for I := 0 to StringGrid2.ColCount - 1 do
    StringGrid2.Cols[I].Clear;

  with StringGrid2 do
  begin
    Cells[0, 0] := 'Mon';
    Cells[1, 0] := 'Tue';
    Cells[2, 0] := 'Wed';
    Cells[3, 0] := 'Thu';
    Cells[4, 0] := 'Fri';
    Cells[5, 0] := 'Sat';
    Cells[6, 0] := 'Sun';
  end;
  // increment to month after first stringgrid
  tNewMonthStart := IncMonth(tCurrentShowMonthStart, 1);
  iWeekCount := 1;
  tTempMonth := tNewMonthStart;

  for I := 1 to DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart) do
  begin

    tTempMonth := IncDay(tNewMonthStart, I - 1);

    if arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate <> 'click here to book' then
    begin
      if tTempMonth = strToDate(arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate) then
      begin
        // save x and y values if test date is on this stringgrid
        StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
          IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
        iCalendarBTestDateXVal := DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1;
        iCalendarBTestDateYVal := iWeekCount;
        bDrawPastTestDate := true;
      end
      else
      begin
        // otherwise just populate
        StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
          IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      end;
      if (tTempMonth < StrToDate(arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate))
        and (I = DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart)) then
      begin
        // set x and y values to last cell because date to be highlightted is in next month
        StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
          IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
        bDrawPastTestDate := true;
        iCalendarBTestDateXVal := 6;
        iCalendarBTestDateYVal := 6;

      end;
      if (tTempMonth > StrToDate(arrCourses[iCourseArrayPointer].getTestDate))
        and (I = 1) then
      begin
        // set x and y values to first because date to be highlightted is in prior month/stringgrid
        StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
          IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
        bDrawPastTestDate := true;
        iCalendarBTestDateXVal := 0;
        iCalendarBTestDateYVal := 0;

      end;

    end
    else
    begin
      StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // otherwise just populate
      bDrawPastTestDate := false;
    end;
    if (tTempMonth < tLastStudyDate) and (I = DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart)) then
    begin
      StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set x and y values to last cell because last cell to be higlighted is in next month
      iCalendarBLastStudyDateXVal := 6;
      iCalendarBLastStudyDateYVal := 6;
    end;

    if (tTempMonth > tLastStudyDate) and (I = 1) then
    begin
      StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set x and y values to last cell because last cell to be higlighted is in prior month/stringgrid
      iCalendarBLastStudyDateXVal := 0;
      iCalendarBLastStudyDateYVal := 0;

    end;
    if tTempMonth = tLastStudyDate then
    begin
      StringGrid2.Cells[DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1, iWeekCount] :=
        IntToStr(DayOfTheMonth(tTempMonth));
      // set x and y values to current cell
      iCalendarBLastStudyDateXVal := DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) - 1;
      iCalendarBLastStudyDateYVal := iWeekCount;

    end;

    if DayOfTheWeek(tTempMonth) = 7 then
    begin
      Inc(iWeekCount);
    end;
  end;

  // iMonth2LastXVal := DayOfWeek(IncDay(tNewMonthStart,
  // (DaysInMonth(tNewMonthStart) - 1) - 1)) - 1;
  // iMonth2LastYVal := iWeekCount;
  StringGrid1.refresh;
  StringGrid2.refresh;
  // ShowMessage(IntToStr(iCal2LastStudyDateXVal));
  // ShowMessage(IntToStr(iCal2LastStudyDateYVal));
end;
```

The next procedure is the `OnDrawCell` procedure that runs every time something on a string grid changes. It is basically identical for `StringGrid1` as `StringGrid2`, except that wherever a variable is `iCalendarB...` it would be `iCalendarA...` for `StringGrid1DrawCell()`.

Read the comments for further explanation on how the cell colouring works. But basically, it uses the `x` and `y` values saved by the `upDateCalendar()` procedure to determine which cells should be highlighted. See the image below for the result.

My issue is that somewhere the `OnDrawCell` is constantly being called, or something is causing the StringGrids to continuously update.

[image]

```
procedure TStudentDashboard.StringGrid2DrawCell(Sender: TObject;
  ACol, ARow: integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin

  StringGrid2.Selection := TGridRect(Rect);
  // if the cell is not empty or fixed
  if (StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow] <> '') and (ARow > 0) then
  begin
    // if the weekday of the cell corresponds with checkboxes
    if (arrWeekDaysSelected[ACol] = true) then
    begin
      // if the cell has these x and y values make it yellow
      if (ACol = iCalendarBLastStudyDateXVal) and
        (ARow = iCalendarBLastStudyDateYVal) then
      begin

        StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $008BECFA; // yellow
        StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
        StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
        StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
          StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
        // StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow] := Copy(StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow],1,StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow].Length-1);
      end
      // only colour the following if the cell has x and y values smaller than i...LastStudyDate..X/Yval
      else if (ARow < iCalendarBLastStudyDateYVal) or
        ((ACol < iCalendarBLastStudyDateXVal) and
        (ARow = iCalendarBLastStudyDateYVal)) then
      begin
        // if the cell has x and y values larger than i...TestDate..X/Yval make red
        if (bDrawPastTestDate = true) and
          (((ARow >= iCalendarBTestDateYVal) and (ACol > iCalendarBTestDateXVal)
          ) or (ARow > iCalendarBTestDateYVal)) then
        begin
          StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00A49FF9; // red
          StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
          StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
          StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
            StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
        end
        // otherwise make it green
        else
        begin
          StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00A4F99F; // green
          StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
          StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
          StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
            StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
        end;

      end
      // otherwise make white
      else
      begin
        StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F1FFFB;
        StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
        StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
        StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
          StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
      end;

    end
    // if cell is the test date make blue

    else if (ACol = iCalendarBTestDateXVal) and (ARow = iCalendarBTestDateYVal)
    then
    begin

      StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F9A49F; // blue
      StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
      StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
        StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
      // StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow] := copy(StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow],1,StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow].Length-1);
      bDrawPastTestDate := true;
    end
    //otherwise make white
    else
    begin
      StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F1FFFB;
      StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
      StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
        StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
    end;
  end
  else if gdFixed in State then
  begin
  end
    //otherwise make white
  else if gdSelected in State then
  begin
    StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F1FFFB;
    StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
    StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
      StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
  end
    //otherwise make white
  else
  begin
    StringGrid2.Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F1FFFB;
    StringGrid2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Roboto Lt';
    StringGrid2.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    StringGrid2.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 3,
      StringGrid2.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
  end;
end;
```

My goal is to stop the redraw loop and flickering. The flickering I can easily remove using `DoubleBuffered := true`, however the event still runs continuously keeping other controls from updated (for example, the CheckBoxes work, but you don't see the tick). I assume that's because of the loop?

Comment: Put BeginUpdate / EndUpdate around any large number of changes to StringGrid content. Usually in a Try / Finally block to make sure updates don't stay off when there is an error.

Comment: Like this ->  try .. stringgrid.beginupdate .....  changes ..... endupdate ....  finally?   Is that the correct format? (sorry I have not used try finally as much before)  Also, what counts as "a large number of changes"?  PS Thank you very much for your response! @Brian

Comment: no: beginupdate- try- actions - finally endupdate end

Comment: I put it just like you said, around every change to the string grid. Did not fix the flickering. Is there perhaps a property that needs to be changed? Something to do with windows perhaps?

Comment: On the first line in `StringGrid2DrawCell()` you call `  StringGrid2.Selection := tGridRect(Rect);`. Why? This is the reason for the constant redrawing. Just throw it away.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg Done that now, but unfortunately, it is still redrawing.

Comment: The reason for constant redrawing of the grid was that you set the `Selection` from within the `OnDrawCell` event, thus triggering a new need to draw and subsequently call `OnDrawCell`. I don't see any other line of code within `StringGrid2DrawCell` that would do something similar. Perhaps you are changing either data or state of `StringGrid2` repeatedly somewhere else in your code.